# Combo Box items - Display Member for List(Of String)?

Tags: vb.net, list, combobox

My project is in Visual Basic. I am trying to create a custom & savable "filter" for a DataGridView using several TextBoxes. Right now, any List(Of String) that is added to the Combo Box is displayed in the box as (Collection). I want my users to be able to select the one they created, so I would like the Lists to have a display name that can be selected in the Combo Box. Here is some of the code.

```
Dim savedFilter As New List(Of String)
savedFilter.Add(NameTextBox.Text)
savedFilter.Add(AgeTextBox.Text)
savedFilter.Add(NotesTextBox.Text)
ComboBoxSavedFilters.Items.Add(savedFilter)
```

Is it possible to add a display name for a List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or if you are lazy use buid-in generic class `Tuple` [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx).

Create collection of `Tuple(Of String, List(Of String))` and use approach suggested by @Plutonix for binding collection to `ComboBox`

```
Dim savedFilter As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, List(Of String)))()
savedFilter.Add(
    Tuple.Create("default",
                 New List From {"filter1", "filter2", "filter3"}))
savedFilter.Add(
    Tuple.Create("Blue ones", 
                 New List From {"filter4", "filter5"}))
savedFilter.Add(
    Tuple.Create("Old ones", 
                 New List From {NameTextBox.Text, AgeTextBox.Text, NotesTextBox.Text}))

With ComboBoxSavedFilters
    .DisplayMember = "Item1" 'Name of first property in Tuple type
    .ValueMember = "Item2" 'Name of second property in Tuple type -List 
    .DataSource = savedFilter       
End With
```

Then `SelectedValue` will contain currently selected filter's collection, 
which can be accessed like  that

```
Dim filter As List(Of String) =
    DirectCast(Me.ComboBoxSavedFilters.SelectedValue, List(Of String))
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I want to designate just one string for display for the entire list. I feel like this would put a value for each field in the combo box when I just wanted one value for the entire list.

Comment: @MattLeverich, just change type of second property to `List(Of String)`, the first property will contain Display name for filter's collection and second property contain collection itself

Comment: Also,, to expand, I want the user to be able to type the name they want for the filter list in the combo box, then push enter to save it

Comment: Because I have a "Save" button that adds a saved filter to the list, for some reason the ComboBox will only display the first value even when I can see that its DataSource is showing all of them. What's the problem there?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup under My.Settings a StriingCollection
[image]

Initializing (you can omit the items added if so desired)

```
If My.Settings.Filters Is Nothing Then
    My.Settings.Filters = New StringCollection() From {"One", "Two"}
End If
```

Setup items in a ComboBox

```
ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(My.Settings.Filters.Cast(Of String).ToArray)
```

Adding an item

```
My.Settings.Filters.Add(Now.ToShortDateString)
```

You can remove and clear items too.

Answer (score 0):

*Provide a Display Member for List(Of String)*

Apparently, these are less a collection of filters than a collection of criteria or clauses for one Filter:

`I condensed the code in the question, but there are 14 fields that can be filtered and there are multiple filters that can be applied on one field.`

For the multiples per field, I am not sure I would want to store those individually, but keep the field criteria together.  So, if you want to apply a name to these, a class would not only do that but could help manage the filter elements:

```
Public Class SuperFilter
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Elements As SortedList

    Public ReadOnly Property FilterText As String
        Get
            Return GetFilterText()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(n As String)
        Name = n
        Elements = New SortedList
    End Sub

    Public Sub AddItem(filter As String)
        Elements.Add(Elements.Count, filter)
    End Sub

    Public Sub InsetAt(index As Int32, filter As String)
        Elements.Add(index, filter)
    End Sub

    Private Function GetFilterText() As String
        Dim els(Elements.Count - 1) As String
        Elements.Values.CopyTo(els, 0)

        Return String.Join(" ", els)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0} ({1})", Name, Elements.Count.ToString)
    End Function
End Class
```

You would need to add methods and properties like `Remove` and `Count` but this should be enough to demonstrate.  I am not sure about the `SortedList`, a `Dictionary` using the field name might be better, but something to control the order seems worthwhile.  I am also unsure I would expose the `Elements` collection - managing it might be better left to the class.

Hopefully, the Combo displaying a set of these (as opposed to the filter elements/clauses) is the goal.

```
Private filters As New List(Of SuperFilter)
```

Add filter items to the list:

```
Dim item As New SuperFilter("Default")
item.AddItem("Id = 7")
filters.Add(item)

item = New SuperFilter("Blue Ones")
item.AddItem("Color = Blue")
filters.Add(item)

item = New SuperFilter("Complex")
item.AddItem("[Name] like %Bob% OR [Name] like %Alice%")
item.AddItem("AND Color = 'Blue'")
item.AddItem("AND Active=True")
item.AddItem("AND AccessRequired < 3")
item.AddItem("AND DateAdded > #2/11/2010#")
item.AddItem("AND CreatedBy = 'ziggy'")
filters.Add(item)

cbo1.DataSource = filters
cbo1.DisplayMember = "Name"
cbo1.ValueMember = "FilterText"
```

The value member could be the `Elements` - the collection of filter clauses, or it could be the query text.  The `GetFilterText` method joins them together for you as part of what a filter manager class could/should:

```
    For n As Int32 = 0 To filters.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}   Count: {1}{2}Text:{3}", filters(n).Name,
                            filters(n).Elements.Count,
                            Environment.NewLine, filters(n).FilterText)
    Next
```

Result:

> Name: Default   Count: 1
>   Text:Id = 7
>   Name: Blue Ones   Count: 1
>   Text:Color = Blue
>   Name: Complex   Count: 6
>   Text:[Name] like %Bob% OR [Name] like %Alice% AND Color = 'Blue' AND Active=True AND AccessRequired < 3 AND DateAdded > #2/11/2010# AND CreatedBy = 'ziggy'

If you use "Elements" as the ValueMember you will get back the collection.

[image][image]

The combo displays the `Name` for the user.  On the right, a label displays the `ValueMember` in this case, it is the `FilterText` or joined `Elements`. As I said, you could get back the actual collection as the `SelectedValue` instead, but that is available as part of `SelectedItem`.

If `savable` means beyond the life of the application instance, that is another question, but these are very easily serialized.

Comment: I condensed the code in the question, but there are 14 fields that can be filtered and there are multiple filters that can be applied on one field. The filtering is done in SQL, so if you elect to do two filers on "Name" i.e. you put "Bob" in one text box and "Alice" in the one below,,, the SQL query would be "...WHERE [Name] like %Bob% OR [Name] like %Alice%". These custom filters need to be saved, and each text box value (including "") are saved in a List(Of String) that is then put in a ComboBox, but I need a name to be attached to that list other than (Collection)

Comment: Also the ComboBox is not required to perform the filter - that is already done using Text_Changed events from the TextBoxes so the DataGridView filters live as you change the values in the TextBoxes

Comment: There is nothing there that cant be done with what I provided.  The filters can be as simple or as complex as you can handle them.  The functional element this provides is assigning a name to them. Text_Changed is a bad place to apply filters

Comment: It's actually a method named concat() that used SQL for the filtering

Comment: I did what you said and the ComboBox populated with every field in the List rather than just one value to represent the entire list. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Revised based on the new premise that you want to save/store filter clauses/elements per filter item.