# Overwriting a saved setting in a CheckBox?

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, combobox, io, tuples

I have a small application that allows the user to check a custom number of CheckBoxes then save that to a ComboBox for selecting later. Right now the ComboBox accepts duplicates and I am trying to remove that and allow a user to overwrite their own particular saved selections. The data in each user's selection is stored first in a List(Of Tuple(Of String, List(Of String) called columnList, where item 1, accessed in a String called name, is the name of the list, and item 2 is the list. For access after closing the program it is also stored in a text file. I have a crude method that is supposed to allow the user to overwrite their own saved selections, where it removes the element at the location where the user's name is, then inserts it with the updated selections in the same place. I also have an int flag to tell the program if the user is overwriting rather than creating a new list.

```
For i = 0 To columnList.Count - 1
            If columnList(i).Item1 = name Then
                columnList.RemoveAt(i)
                columnList.Insert(i, Tuple.Create(name, customList))
                flag = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If flag = 0 Then
            columnList.Add(Tuple.Create(name, customList))
        End If
```

The problem is that this is not deleting the data in the text file, rather adding another list of selections with a duplicate name to the file. So it works until you close the application, then when it reopens the original list is still displayed in the ComboBox along with the new list under a duplicate name at the bottom. I want to edit the storage text file directly from the application.

Comment: Since [this answer from Fabio](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35021092/1070452) is apprently working for you, perhaps you could take a moment to accept that answer by clicking the checkmark (and maybe some of the other answers youve gotten).  This helps others find good answers, as does upvoting which comes at 15 rep.

Comment: ColumnList(I).Item1 ->>> That's not name, that's an integer. What you have written will not compile I believe - so I am not sure how you were able to get it running. Use Nefariis solution - simple solution.

Comment: Done! Sorry I'm new to StackOverflow

Comment: @Maertin ColumnList is a List of Tuples, so yes it does compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a little unclear, so let me know if I understand you correctly.

1. program opens (works)
2. user data/preferences are loaded from text file(works)
3. user changes preferences(works)
4. user exits out of program
5. when user reloads program, old data and new data are both loaded (this is what you want to change)

If the above is the case then what you need to do is to overwrite the file instead of appending the file.

```
Dim sw As Streamwriter = New Streamwriter("C:\myFile.txt", False)
```

The true at the end tells the file to overwrite instead of just writing to the bottom.

If this is not what you are talking about, can you please edit your question in the above format, so we can see where exactly you are having the issue?

Comment: Yes I would probably need to overwrite the entire file but I was seeing if there was a simpler way. If Sally selects the 4th value in the ComboBox out of 6, changes two things in her selected list of checkboxes and clicks save I would have to overwrite everyone's lists in the text file,, not just her's.

Comment: If you are set on using text files, I would have every user create their own file. Then have them all in a seperate folder that loads using a for loop for all files with extension ".txt" ... If there are more then a handful of users, I would actually create a SQL DB for the information (not hard in VS).

Comment: The only way to do it in a single text is to read the whole file in, create a stringbuilder, then add line by line in the SB until you get to the place where you either want to insert or delete, read in the rest of the file, then save the stringbuilder over your original file .... this will be by far less efficient.

Comment: You might have the "true" backwards. The Boolean property in the StreamWriter declaration is called Append, and I believe you set it to true if you want it to append to the file and false otherwise.